# EJS console.log() does print correctly, but it doesn't while writing it to the table

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, ejs

Good Day everybody

If i use a console.log it prints it correctly, but it doesn't write it to a table. And i have no idea why it doesn't. Can someone help me please?

My EJS looks like this:

```
<% insrtdJngls.forEach((item) => { %>
                        <tr></tr>
                            <% console.log(item, "ejs print") %>
                            <% console.log(item.insrtdDateiname, "ejs print") %>
                            <td id="table_firma" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdFirmaname%></td>
                            <td id="dateiname_table" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdDateiname%></td>
                            <td id="table_time" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdDateTime%></td>

                            <form method="post" action="/deleteOne">
                                <td><button class="DelOne"><img
                                            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/empty-trash.png" /></button></td>
                            </form>

                            <form method="post" action="/deleteAll">
                                <td><button class="DelAllBtn"><img
                                            src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency-systems-regular/25/000000/garbage-truck.png" /></button>
                                </td>
                            </form>
                            <% }); %>
```

And my ejs print looks like this:

```
{
  insrtdDateTime: 2022-01-12T01:18:00.000Z,
  insrtdDateiname: 'fantaWerbung',
  insrtdFirmaname: 'Fanta'
} ejs print
fantaWerbung ejs print
{
  insrtdDateTime: 2022-01-13T01:18:00.000Z,
  insrtdDateiname: 'fantaWerbung',
  insrtdFirmaname: 'Fanta'
} ejs print
fantaWerbung ejs print
```

But in the td, there is no output at all... if i write it with just item, it shows me, that there is one object, can someone explain?

Why doesn't it write to the table like fantaWerbung? Because obviously the data it receives is correct...

Thanks a lot
Mats Groeneweg

Answer (score 0):

Place `form` inside the `td`:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<% insrtdJngls.forEach((item) => { %>
                        <tr>
                            <% console.log(item, "ejs print") %>
                            <% console.log(item.insrtdDateiname, "ejs print") %>
                            <td id="table_firma" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdFirmaname%></td>
                            <td id="dateiname_table" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdDateiname%></td>
                            <td id="table_time" class="tdList"><%=item.insrtdDateTime%></td>

                            <td>
                            <form method="post" action="/deleteOne">
                                <button class="DelOne"><img
                                            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/empty-trash.png" /></button>
                            </form>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            <form method="post" action="/deleteAll">
                                <button class="DelAllBtn"><img
                                            src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency-systems-regular/25/000000/garbage-truck.png" /></button>
                                
                            </form>
                            </td>
                            
                            </tr>
                            <% }); %>
</tbody>
</table>
```